# CSS Boxlayout Height expand

Tags: html, css

I want to create a Box Layout. It should like my Layout but expanded to the bottom. The boxes should end at the bottom of the display.

I try it with `height : 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;` but the boxes doesnt expand to the bottom.

Is there a solution to expand this boxes from top to bottom, like from left to right?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height:100%; 
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
 
.columnsmall {
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}

.columnmiddle {
    float: right;
    width: 34%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}

.columnbig {
    float: left;
    width: 66%;
    padding:10px;
    height: 80px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnbig" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#bbb;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  </div>
</div>

    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by expand to the bottom? you want the divs to fill up the window?

Comment: consider grid or flex

Comment: @Anurag Daolagajao yes i want to fill up a 16:9 display with this boxes, there this shown in fullscreen without resize

Comment: you have defined height to child columns? in that way it can't expand more.. you should try with percent or flex laoyut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try flex to build your layout then easily manage height/width with **%** or **vh** values

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:nth-child(2) {
  height: 30vh;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.columnsmall {
  width: 20%;
}

.columnmiddle {
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
}

.columnbig {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnbig" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#aaa;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#bbb;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnsmall" style="background-color:#ccc;">
  </div>
  <div class="columnmiddle" style="background-color:#ddd;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

*It will set the min-height to viewport(display size) height.*